# Show legend using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts, legend, fusioncharts

I'm creating some charts using Fusion Charts. Due to some problem, I have to display legends separately and not use the legends provided by fusion charts.
I have a table data in which I have status and their hex colors.

```
status  code
A       #006400
B       #FFFFFF
C       #FFFF00
D       #90EE90
E       #FFA500
```

I need to display this in the form of legend on my page using jquery or javascript.
Something like
A and then show color of A
B and then show color of B
and so on.

Can anyone give me an idea how it can be done?
Thanks.

Comment: Is this solution completely independent from Fusion charts? Does there need to be a connection between the legend made by jQuery and what is happening with Fusion charts?

Comment: Yes, this will be completely independent from fusion charts

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can store your table data as **json**:

```
legend_data = [
    {
    'status' : 'A',
    'code' : '#006400'
    },
    {
    'status' : 'B',
    'code' : '#FFFFFF'
    },
    {
    'status' : 'C',
    'code' : '#FFFF00'
    },
    {
    'status' : 'D',
    'code' : '#90EE90'
    },
    {
    'status' : 'E',
    'code' : '#FFA500'
    }
    ]
```

Create a **div** in your html that will hold legend info:

```
<html>
<body>
<div id='legend'></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Add CSS **styling**:

```
body {
  color: white;
}
#legend {
  width: 100px; 
  height: 150px; 
  border-radius: 3px; 
  background: grey;
  padding: 10px;  
  font-family: arial; 
}
.circle {
  width: 20px; 
  border-radius: 100%;
}
```

Write a **function** in JS/jQuery that will *load your legend_data* into the #legend div:

```
function create_legend() {
   $.each(legend_data, function(index, element) {
       col = element.code;
       $('#legend').append("<table width='100%'><td align='center' style='font-size: 20px'>" + element.status + "</td><td align='center'><div class='circle' style='background: " + col + "'>&nbsp;</div></td></table>"); 
   });
}

create_legend();
```

Here is the **result**:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can try this,

**JS code:**

```
 var StatusDiv = '';
  $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: 'URL',
            dataType: "JSON ",
            success: function (data) {
                var result = data;
                $.each(result, function (i, Status) {
                    StatusDiv += '<div style="font-size:12px;margin-right:8px;float:left;" title="' + Status.name + '"><div style="height:15px;width:15px;margin-top:0px;background-color:' + Status.color + ';float:left"></div><div style="float:none;padding-left:17px;">' + Status.name + '</div></div>';
                });
                $('#StatusColorDescription').html(StatusDiv);
            },
            error: function (result) {
            }
        });
```

**HTML:**

```
<div id="StatusColorDescription" style="float:left"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use **`"colorrange":`** property for legends color condition or for more help visit this article...
[legend-options](https://www.fusioncharts.com/dev/chart-guide/heat-map-chart/legend-options.html)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have tried this.I'm using a stack chart,so this doesn't work in the way I want.

Comment: Yes I'm using fusion charts to display the stack chart. In this chart some series Names are repeated based on the data.The problem here is, when ever the series is getting repeated, it is shown separately in the legend again.I want to avoid that.